# Copy data to clipboard with js / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a code and I display to the user a table with data from DB.
The user can copy all the data manually, but I want to add a button that copy automatically the data to clipboard.
How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Try this code

`function ClipBoard() 
{
holdtext.innerText = copytext.innerText;
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}`

Comment: Quick internet search show some solution, this have been previously asked on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with javascript. 
There is no browser that can allow that. It's a security issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about that -  [This website](http://flatuicolors.com/) allows you to click on HTML colors and have them pasted into your clipboard - works fine on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you are good with JQuery, use this [Library](http://www.paulund.co.uk/jquery-copy-clipboard)

**P.S**  Although it raise a security concern, most of the browsers doesn't allow it.